# conversion of .cc file to object file

Tags: ns2

pl help how to convert a cc file to a object file.what is the command need for that and in which environment it will work

Answer (score 2):

A `.cc` file is a typical extension for a C++ source code file (some others include `.cxx` and `.cpp`). A compiler is needed to turn it into an object file. One very popular encoder is `g++`:

```
g++ -c -o something.o something.cc
```